# Statistics of connected-component sizes of minimum-weight $f$-factors in random planar geometric graphs

Tags: graph-theory, st.statistics, random-graphs, regular-graph

An $f$-factor is an $f$-regular subgraph with the same vertex set $V$ and a subset of the edges $E$ of some given undirected graph $G(V,E)$

> **Question:**
>
> what is known about the statistical properties of the *sizes*, i.e. number of vertices, of the connected components of minimum-weight $f$-factors of complete graphs that are induced by a random, uniformly distributed set of points in the unit square of the euclidean plane and edge weights equal to euclidean distance?